# Do not add glossaries entries to numberlist from inside the glossary

Tags: glossaries

With the `glossaries` package and activated numberlist, I want to avoid that a reference appears inside the numberlist, when I reference an entry using one of the `\gls`-like commands inside another entry of the glossary. Effectively, the numberlist should only show pages inside the main document that referenced to the respective entries.

Here is an MWE to demonstrate what I want to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nopostdot,style=indexgroup,nolist]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{target}
{
    name={target},
    description={Foo foo bar. Page 2 should not appear here.}
}
\newglossaryentry{link}
{
    name={link},
    description={This one has a \gls{target}, but this use of \gls{target} should not appear in the numberlist.}
}

\begin{document}

This usage of \gls{target} should appear in the number list.

We also have \glspl{link} here.

\newpage

\printnoidxglossary

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just the base `glossaries` package you can use `\glshyperlink` instead of `\gls`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nopostdot,style=indexgroup,nolist]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{target}
{
    name={target},
    description={Foo foo bar. Page 2 should not appear here.}
}
\newglossaryentry{link}
{
    name={link},
    description={This one has a \glshyperlink{target}, but this use of
    \glshyperlink{target} should not appear in the numberlist.}
}

\begin{document}

This usage of \gls{target} should appear in the number list.

We also have \glspl{link} here.

\newpage

\printnoidxglossary

\end{document}
```

This omits page 2 from the number list:

[image: image of glossary]

Without `hyperref`, `\glshyperlink{label}` effectively just does `\glsentrytext{label}`. With `hyperref`, it will also have a hyperlink.

With the [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package you can switch off indexing with the `noindex` option. (The `nopostdot` option is automatically implemented. For some reason, `glossaries-extra` doesn't seem to like `nolist`, so I've removed it. I'll look into that.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=indexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{target}
{
    name={target},
    description={Foo foo bar. Page 2 should not appear here.}
}
\newglossaryentry{link}
{
    name={link},
    description={This one has a \gls{target}, but this use of
    \gls{target} should not appear in the numberlist.}
}

\begin{document}

This usage of \gls{target} should appear in the number list.

We also have \glspl{link} here.

\newpage

\GlsXtrSetDefaultGlsOpts{noindex}

\printnoidxglossary

\end{document}
```

In both examples, if `target` isn't indexed elsewhere in the document it won't appear in the glossary. The result is the same as before.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to use the `nolist` option due to compatibility issues. With `glshyperlink`, are there also plural forms etc?

Comment: @languitar `\glshyperlink` has an optional argument, so you could do `\glshyperlink[\glsentryplural{label}]{label}` (or you can just to `\glsentryplural{label}` if you're not using `hyperref`). I'll see if I can get the `nolist` bug fix.

Comment: @languitar The `nolist` problem was caused by a weird interaction between `glossaries.sty` and `glossaries-extra.sty`. I've fixed the problem by making a minor alteration to `glossaries.sty`. So to fix the `nolist` bug in `glossaries-extra.sty` you need at least v4.31 (2017-08-10) of the base `glossaries.sty`. (Allow a few days for the new version to make it into the TeX distributions.)

Comment: But the fixed version is already on CTAN? I could put it to my project for now.

Comment: @languitar Check if http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/README shows v4.31. If it's still showing v4.30 then the new version hasn't reached your closest mirror, otherwise you can download the [`glossaries.tds.zip`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries.tds.zip) TDS archive and [extract it to your TEXMFHOME directory](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/installsty.html).

Comment: @languitar  Alternatively just copy the `glossaries.sty` file to your document's directory as a temporary fix. That's the only file that's been changed (aside from version details)

Comment: Thanks, I could make it work by copying the sty file. However, I now have a follow up question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385885/glossaries-dual-entries-prevent-page-from-acronym-list-appearing-in-number-list