# glossaries dual entries: prevent page from acronym list appearing in glossary number list

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

As a follow up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385677): when using the `newdualentry` command provided as an example in the `glossaries` package, how do I prevent the number list of the glossary entry to contain the page where the acronym list references the glossary entry.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}
\RestoreAcronyms

\newcommand*{\newdualentry}[5][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{main-#2}{name={#4},%
  text={#3\glsadd{#2}},%
  description={#5},%
  #1
  }%
  \newacronym{#2}{#3\glsadd{main-#2}}{#4}
}

\newdualentry{svm}% label
  {SVM}% abbreviation
  {support vector machine}% long form
  {Statistical pattern recognition technique}% description
\newacronym{FOO}{FOO}{This should still work}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\gls{svm}. Also \gls{FOO}.

\newpage

\GlsXtrSetDefaultGlsOpts{noindex}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The "support vector machine" entry in the glossary shall only have page 1 in its number list and the other acronym without accompanying glossary entry should still be usable.

[image]

What I have tried was the following rewrite of the command definition:

```
\newcommand*{\newdualentry}[5][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{main-#2}{name={#4},%
  text={#3\glsadd{#2}},%
  description={#5},%
  #1
  }%
  \newacronym{#2}{\gls[noindex=true]{main-#2}}{#4}
}
```

However, with this version, the long entry doesn't appear at all and it kills the automatic linking of page numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\glsadd` doesn't recognise the `noindex` key. (The purpose of `\glsadd` is to index without generating any text, so `noindex` doesn't make sense in this context.) This means that any instance of `\glsadd` that ends up in the glossary (through the short form appearing in the entry's `name` field) won't be affected by `\GlsXtrSetDefaultGlsOpts{noindex}`.

In this case a better approach would be to move `\glsadd` to the post-link hook which is done after commands like `\gls`. `\newacronym` sets the `category` to `acronym` by default, so the post-link hook is `\glsxtrpostlinkacronym`. (`\newglossaryentry` sets `category` to `general` by default, so the post-link hook for the `main-svm` entry is `\glsxtrpostlinkgeneral` instead.) Within the post-link hook, you can reference the entry label with `\glslabel`.

Then just redefine `\glsxtrpostlinkacronym` to do nothing before the glossaries in the event that `\gls{svm}` is used in any of the descriptions.

Modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkacronym}{\glsadd{main-\glslabel}}

\newcommand*{\newdualentry}[5][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{main-#2}{name={#4},%
  text={#3\glsadd{#2}},%
  description={#5},%
  #1
  }%
  \newacronym{#2}{#3}{#4}
}

\newdualentry{svm}% label
  {SVM}% abbreviation
  {support vector machine}% long form
  {Statistical pattern recognition technique}% description

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\gls{svm}.

\newpage

\GlsXtrSetDefaultGlsOpts{noindex}
\renewcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkacronym}{}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossaries]

If you have non-dual entries, you could set the `category` in `\newdualentry` to something other than the default `acronym`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[dualacronym]{short}% change as appropriate

\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkdualacronym}{\glsadd{main-\glslabel}}

\newcommand*{\newdualentry}[5][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{main-#2}{name={#4},%
  text={#3\glsadd{#2}},%
  description={#5},%
  #1
  }%
  \newacronym[category=dualacronym]{#2}{#3}{#4}
}

\newdualentry{svm}% label
  {SVM}% abbreviation
  {support vector machine}% long form
  {Statistical pattern recognition technique}% description

\newacronym{ex}{EX}{example}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\gls{svm}. \gls{ex}.

\newpage

\GlsXtrSetDefaultGlsOpts{noindex}
\renewcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkdualacronym}{}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well in my isolated test case. But I can't get this working in my main document. There, I get an error everytime I try to use an acronym with `\gls`: "Glossary entry `main-XXX' has not been defined.". I can't find the difference. Porting over all special settings to example here doesn't produce this error. Any idea?

Comment: This error appears as soon as I defined the post-link command.

Comment: @languitar The post-link command is the place where `\glsadd{main-XXX}` is occurring. In your `\newdualentry` command, check that the first argument of `\newglossaryentry` (`main-#2`) matches the `#2` label in `\newacronym`. Other things to check: are the definitions all in the preamble (or `\input` in the preamble)? Do you have [nested link-text](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:nested)? Does the `XXX` part match the argument of `\gls`? What happens if you try doing `\glsadd{main-XXX}` directly in your document?

Comment: Yikes, I see the issue. I have also acronyms, which do not have an accompanying full entry in the glossary. So I would need some way to restrict the link magic only to acronyms defined with the dual command.

Comment: I have updated the question to include such a case.

Comment: @languitar Sorry, I should've taken that into account. I've updated my answer.